# jOOQ returns wrong column value from record

Tags: kotlin, jooq

I have the following record resulting from a query with a couple of joins:

[image: record variable]

Now when I try to retrieve a particular column which is not in the result with:

```kotlin
record[REG_MEDEWERKER.ID]
```

where `REG_MEDEWERKER.ID` is generated Kotlin code having the following details:

[image: REG_MEDEWERKER.ID field]

I expect to get `null`. However, the wrong id value (of `zkn_zaak.id`) is returned instead.

What am I missing here? Shouldn't jOOQ have enough information (table and field name) to retrieve the correct column from the record?

============ Update =============

From the code it seems this is intended behavior and it is already discussed extensively in e.g.
https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/4471,
https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/4455,
https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/4476 and https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/10266

So this explains a lot.

However, the question remains how I can determine that column `REG_MEDEWERKER.ID` is not in the result set...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Record.get(Field)](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/Record.html#get(org.jooq.Field)) Javadoc:

> If this record contains a field with the same Field.getName() as the argument field, that value is retrieved.

So the value is retrieved based on the unqualified column name. Only if that column name is ambiguous, qualification is taken into consideration to attempt to disambiguate the column name.

While this may lead to the unexpected result you're experiencing, it has a lot of advantages when working with aliased tables, derived tables, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the reaction. Is there another way to see if the column is in the result? Something like `Record.getStrict(Field)`?

Comment: @Jippe: `Record.field(Field)` will produce the *actual* field in the record. You can then check if the qualified names are the same.

Comment: Still, from all the `SQLWarning`'s in the logging I get the feeling that this is not a best practice. Is it better to use aliases in the select to disambiguate the fields?

Comment: @Jippe: I can't say from your current question, you haven't posted the query...

Comment: You can find the query in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/jippeholwerda/cd2e2fd97cb2072a00cf0b5bbe0d661b)

Comment: @Jippe: But why are you trying to read `REG_MEDEWERKER.ID` from it? Or is that just a mistake and you'd like to fail early?

Comment: I use the same code for turning the record into a data class for when the `REG_MEDEWERKER` table is (left) joined). It is an optional field, that I want to convert whenever the `REG_MEDEWERKER.ID` field is in the record set.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225202/discussion-between-jippe-and-lukas-eder).

Answer (score 2):

Implemented the following Kotlin extension method that returns the value of the record only if the qualified name of the field matches the qualified name of the field in the record (see Lukas Eder's answer):

```kotlin
fun <T> Record.getStrict(field: Field<T>): T? =
    this.field(field)?.qualifiedName
        ?.takeIf { field.qualifiedName == it }
        ?.let { this[field] }
```